# Where can I get the 10.6 SDK for XCode

Tags: xcode, macos

Where can I get the 10.6 SDK for XCode? I have the beta of Snow Leopard, and I installed XCode off of the DVD, but it only installed the 10.5 and 10.4 SDKs. I need to build against 10.6 to verify a bug for Apple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ADC Member Site](https://connect.apple.com). Login and select downloads. If you're a Premier or Select member, that should be where you'll find it.

If you're not a Premier or Select member, you won't see it.

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the beta then?

Comment: Somebody at my company has the Premier account, they assigned me a ADC Software Seed Key for Snow Leopard. I guess I can get them to do the same for the SDK? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/)?

Comment: Yup, but I don't see it there anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Note that before you download it you're going to click through a nondisclosure agreement that says that you can't discuss it in public forums, like, well, here...